# Folding an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, f#, concatenation

I'm trying to fold an array of arrays of strings into a single string but I'm not having much luck. Unfortunately it seems `Array.reduce` expects my lambda to return an array of strings because it is an array of array of strings.

I'm getting :

> Line error 37: The type 'string[]' does not match the type 'string'

This is the offending line

```
(fold state) + (fold item)
```

Because it's expecting the lambda to return a `string[]`

Here is the code:

```
let splitStr (seperator: string[]) (str: string) = str.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None)
let convertFile fileName =
    let arrayToTransaction arr =
        let rec foldArray index (sb: StringBuilder) (arr:string[]) =
            if index > 5 then sb.ToString()
            else 
                let text = 
                    match index with
                    | 0 -> sb.Append(DateTime.Parse(arr.[1]).ToString("dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    | 1 -> sb.Append(arr.[0].Substring(0, arr.[0].IndexOf(',')).Trim())
                    | 2 -> sb.Append("Test")
                    | 3 -> sb.Append("Test")
                    | 4 -> sb.Append(Single.Parse(arr.[2].Substring(arr.[2].IndexOf('-') + 1)).ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    | _ -> sb.Append(String.Empty)
                foldArray (index + 1) (text.Append(",")) arr

        arr 
        |> Array.map (splitStr [|"\n"|])
        |> Array.reduce (fun state item -> let fold x = foldArray 0 (new StringBuilder()) x
                                           (fold state) + (fold item))

    File.ReadAllText(fileName)
    |> splitStr [|"\r\n\r\n"|]
    |> arrayToTransaction
```

Comment: I am pretty sure we don't have 37 lines here.  Please show which line has the error

Comment: I've added a clarification on the offending line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda in the `Array.reduce` must return a `string[]` since the signature of the lambda is `'T->'T->'T` and the first `'T` is already unified as `string[]` so the result should also be a `string[]`

Comment: Yeah, I managed to solve it by mutating the collection before reducing it with `Array.map`.

Comment: Great, the error message was a bit confusing because it was marking only the last term of the expression.